# QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont works in Embedded Linux, but not in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, fonts

I have an app developed with Qt 4.8 compiled for both Embedded Linux Arm as well as Linux Ubuntu. It uses a specific set of fonts which I need to have installed for it to run, something I do with `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont`. Everything works fine when I compile for Embedded Linux, but when I do it for Linux Ubuntu, I got -1 and the fonts are not loaded.

I tried to find on the web a solution for the problem but I found no help. Similar problems were solved by updating Qt 4.6 to 4.7 (nothing of use) or by installing `fontconfig`, which I already have. Also I couldn't find anything useful in Qt Assistant and checked the paths to the .ttf files.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
QFontDatabase::removeAllApplicationFonts();

QDir fontDir(DEFAULT_FONTS_PATH);
QStringList fontFileList = fontDir.entryList(QStringList("*.ttf"), QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotDot | QDir::NoDot);

mDebugS(QString("Found %1 fonts on folder theme/fonts").arg(fontFileList.size()));

//
qint32 fontId;

foreach (const QString& filename, fontFileList)
{
    fontId = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(DEFAULT_FONTS_PATH "/" + filename);

    if (Q_UNLIKELY(fontId == -1))
    {
        const QString strTemp = QString("Unable to install font %1").arg(filename);

        mLog(strTemp);
        mDebugS(strTemp);
    }
    else
        applicationFontsIdList.append(fontId);
}

mDebugS(QString::number(applicationFontsIdList.size()) + " fonts are installed");
```

Comment: This question might be quite old but I ran in the same problem. Are there any clues how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Qt (for embedded) 4.8.6. To solve the font problem you need to tell Qt to enable support for the fontconfig tool when building it for the non-embedded environment. Information can be found in the documentation ([Qt for X11 Requirements](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/requirements-x11.html))

You need to install the developer package of fontconfig on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev
```

Before building Qt from source you then need to specify the following option in the configure step:

```
-fontconfig
```

When building my application with this version of Qt addApplicationFont works properly and everything looks great.