# Same QFont configuration leading to different fonts between Embedded Linux and Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, fonts

I'm facing a problem: I developed an app for Embedded Linux using Qt 4.8 where all the fonts are correct and fine. But when I compile the same app for Linux Ubuntu, all fonts become disorganized and ill-formed.

The be sure both had the same font configuration, I read the font configuration of one of the labels both in the Embedded compilation using `QFont::toString()` and in the Ubuntu configuration and they were both equals (`DejaVu Sans,20,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0`).

I also checked the default font configuration using the same function from `QApplication::font()` and everything is the same.

Here is a picture of the correct version in Embedded Linux:

[image: Correct fonts]

And here is the picture of labels with the same configuration:

[image: Wrong fonts]

The font values mentioned above are about the big title font in the top centre.

So what could be going on giving the fact I'm using the same Qt version (4.8), same OS (Linux, even tough one is Embedded for ARM and other is Ubuntu 14) and same font configuration in both? And how could I fix this so the Ubuntu fonts would like exactly like the Embedded Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the same font. My guess is that DejaVu Sans is not installed on your Ubuntu system because of the ragged look of the text; Qt probably picked a substitute font.

Note that QFont::toString() only returns what you have set, not what is *chosen* by the underlying font system. Use QFontInfo to see what the 'real' font is:

> The QFontInfo class provides the same access functions as QFont, e.g.
>   family(), pointSize(), italic(), weight(), fixedPitch(), styleHint()
>   etc. But whilst the QFont access functions return the values that were
>   set, a QFontInfo object returns the values that apply to the font that
>   will actually be used to draw the text.

Comment: well, you're right! Using `QFontInfo` I discovered the Embedded Linux compilation is using `Bitstream Vera Sans` (what makes sense since this was the right font to load since the beginning) while Ubuntu is using `Nimbus Sans L`. Unfortunately I'm not being able to install BVS in Ubuntu as reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286837/qfontdatabaseaddapplicationfont-works-in-embedded-linux-but-not-in-linux-ubun . I'll try a turn around but if yo have any further suggestions, I'll be glad.

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to copy the font file over from one system to the other, though my knowledge about Embedded Linux and its fonts is null so I don't know if there is such a thing as a font file in EL. BTW, you shouldn't have to add the font programmatically from within your program, the user should install the font. And even if he did, there's still no guarantee it will look the same. In other words, hard-coding widths and heights to accomodate a font is almost guaranteed to fail on *some* systems. Rather adjust your labels based on the font (and Qt can do that for you).